# Add Above Footer Widget Area

Tags: wordpress, laravel-blade, roots-sage

I am new to Sage.
How can I added a new ‘above footer’ widget area?

Thank you!

*PS - Does anyone know where the best place to start is to learn Sage. What are the best Laraval Blade tutorials? I am visual so I prefer video.*

Comment: From [Sage's Configuration documentation](https://roots.io/sage/docs/configuration/) it looks like you can register new sidebars via `app/setup.php`, that should get you on the right track I think. Have a look at the docs for more details: https://roots.io/sage/docs/

Comment: Thank you for the resource @cabrerahector